# How to check if a number is in a web element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to trigger an action when the number 1 appears on a web element, but how do I check for it?

This is what I am trying to do, and I get the error 'WebElement' is not iterable

```
   def is_0(self):
    nav = Chrome()
    nav.set_window_size(1360, 760)
    while True:
        if 1 in nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/nav/ul/li[4]/a/span/b'):
            break
        else:
            print('Verificando')
            sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a text of an element, you should use ".text" or ".get_attribute('innerHTML')". I used ".get_attribute('innerHTML')" in my code.

Please refer to my code.

```
def is_0(self):
    nav = Chrome()
    nav.set_window_size(1360, 760)
    while True:
        if '1' in nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/nav/ul/li[4]/a/span/b').get_attribute('innerHTML'):
            break
        else:
            print('Verificando')
            sleep(2)
```

Comment: Would this work if the hmtl had a class name with the searched string in it? e.g. `<div class="test1">`, which apparently is not wanted by OP

Comment: In your case, you can use .get_attribute('class')

.get_attribute('class') extracts the class name.

Comment: I know this is not clear in the question, but I meant to propose a case when you want to find the element with text `this text contains number 1 (one)`, and somewhere another element had `class="test1"`

Comment: Do you mean both cases where number 1 is containted in text and class name?

Comment: How would you find only the element which contains the substring as text, not as class name?

Comment: Did you use .get_attribute('innerHTML')?